# Publish/Get last message when a new subscriber subscribes to a topic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have few publishers in my system, some of them publish at a pre-defined rate and other publish only when there is a change in their variable value.  I was wondering if there is a way, when a new subscriber subscribes after the node has started and the subscriber should receive the last published message.

It's not related to loos of packet. It's just that the subscriber doesn't exists when the publisher published previous message.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379964/publish/get-last-message-when-a-new-subscriber-subscribes-to-a-topic/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(With the preface that I haven't actually implemented this myself yet, so I can't guarantee that it works) it seems like setting the DDS Quality of Service setting of your publisher to `transient local` might do the trick. More on QoS options [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html)

[This tutorial](https://surfertas.github.io/ros2/2019/08/17/ros2-qos.html) may help with modifying the default QoS for a publisher.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2021-06-10**:
Thanks @shonigmann . I made a quick test and it is working..
But for the benefit of other people landing here: latch is the key word, Here is an example from other [ros-answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/305795/ros2-latching/)

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-06-10**:
Great to hear it worked out, thanks for the update

**Comment by [hacker1024](https://answers.ros.org/users/128507/hacker1024/) on 2023-02-26**:
This will also only work correctly if a reliable reliability is selected.